# regex for a string that can't contain # or &

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a regular expression that contains one capital letter, 8-25 characters long, and contains one special character (excluding `#` and `&`). Here is what I have:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z]).{8,25}$/
```

What do I need to add so that the regex does not accept the string if it contains a `#` or `&`?

Comment: what are the allowed special characters? Anything else, including ☀ and ☎ :D

Comment: specifically, special characters can be anything expcept # or &

Comment: if you just check the length with pure javascript, the regex could be much more simple

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z])[^#&]{8,25}$/
```

Explanation:

- `(?=.*[A-Z])` means that the match succeeds only if there is 0-n characters, followed by a capital letter.
- `(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z])` means that the match succeeds only if there is 0-n characters, followed by a character that is not 0-9, a-z or A-Z.
- `[^#&]{8,25}` means that the main match must consist of 8-25 characters, none of which can be `#` or `&`

Answer (score 1):

`.` will match any character apart from newline; replace it with `[^#&]`:

`/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z])[^#&]{8,25}$/`

Comment: But it was right when I reloaded the page after submitting so you should get the upvotes too :)

Comment: Yeah, I read the ?= as ?: at first.  Working on a smaller screen than what I'm used to!